# できる after したがい meaning, and also what does "が," mean?

Tags: grammar, words

I read the definition of a word I'm pretty sure means crusty scab [瘡蓋]{かさぶた}:

> できもの・傷口が，治るに**したがいできる**皮膜。

I believe this means "a film-membrane that can (?) follow up to fix a wound". I'm not sure however what したがいできる (従い出来る？) means here.

Also, I have also seen this が and then a comma (が,) many times when reading the definitions of words. Is this your normal subject marker が with an omitted part after it?

> できもの・傷口**が，**治るにしたがいできる皮膜。

Comment: Just to add context, looks like [it's an entry from 大辞林](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E5%A4%A7%E8%BE%9E%E6%9E%97/prefix/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%95%E3%81%B6%E3%81%9F)?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

にしたがい expresses that one thing changes at the same time as another thing, with a causal relationship. XにしたがいY = "as X happens, Y happens"

> 傷口が，治るにしたがいできる皮膜
> A membrane which is made **as** the wound heals.

I'm sure が is the normal subject particle but I'm afraid I have no idea what the comma is for.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer says, に従い expresses that one thing takes place simultaneously with something else. Here's what A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar has to say (page 269):

[image: dictionary entry 1]
[image: formation rules]

So this becomes "A membrane that forms as a pimple or wound heals". Note that できる means something more like "to be made" here.

が is definitely just the subject particle, there isn't an omission.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was no omission but nice to have confirmation.